# Tooltip alignment issue in IE9 and IE10

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip

I am a Perl developer.

I was told to add Tooltip to few of our links. I added the code in our page. The Tooltip event occurs on `onmouseover` event.

Please have a look at the screenshot:

[image]

But this is not appear proper in IE9 and IE10

Please have a look at the screenshot:

[image]

I added `postion: absolute` and `postion: relative` both CSS but could not solve the issue. Please help.

Found the same topic [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/javascript-information-visualization-toolkit/Us5YIw3_qFQ/JTo1lsOkVkgJ) but could not understand, what changes do I need to make!

**My Code:**

```
<a onmouseover="this.T_ABOVE=true;this.T_OFFSETY=25;this.T_WIDTH=150;this.T_STATIC=true;this.T_DELAY=100;return escape('Click here to read more.');" target="_blank" href="#" class="blue_link">AOL accidentally released</a>
```

**tooltip.js file:**

```
var ttBgColor="#e6ecff";var ttBgImg="";var ttBorderColor="#003399";var ttBorderWidth=1;var ttDelay=500;var ttFontColor="#000066";var ttFontFace="arial,helvetica,sans-serif";var ttFontSize="11px";var ttFontWeight="normal";var ttOffsetX=8;var ttOffsetY=19;var ttPadding=3;var ttShadowColor="";var ttShadowWidth=0;var ttTitleColor="#ffffff";var ttWidth=300;var tt_tags=new Array("a","area","b","big","caption","center","code","dd","div","dl","dt","em","h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6","i","img","input","li","map","ol","p","pre","s","small","span","strike","strong","sub","sup","table","td","th","tr","tt","u","var","ul","layer");var tt_obj,tt_objW=0,tt_objH=0,tt_objX=0,tt_objY=0,tt_offX=0,tt_offY=0,xlim=0,ylim=0,tt_above=false,tt_static=false,tt_sticky=false,tt_wait=false,tt_vis=false,tt_dwn=false,tt_u="undefined",tt_inputs=new Array();var tt_db=(document.compatMode&&document.compatMode!="BackCompat")?document.documentElement:document.body?document.body:null,tt_n=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();var tt_op=!!(window.opera&&document.getElementById),tt_op6=tt_op&&!document.defaultView,tt_ie=tt_n.indexOf("msie")!=-1&&document.all&&tt_db&&!tt_op,tt_n4=(document.layers&&typeof document.classes!="undefined"),tt_n6=(!tt_op&&document.defaultView&&typeof document.defaultView.getComputedStyle!="undefined"),tt_w3c=!tt_ie&&!tt_n6&&!tt_op&&document.getElementById;tt_n="";function tt_Int(b){var a;return isNaN(a=parseInt(b))?0:a}function wzReplace(b,a){var d="",c=this,e;while((e=c.indexOf(b))!=-1){d+=c.substring(0,e)+a;c=c.substring(e+b.length)}return d+c}String.prototype.wzReplace=wzReplace;function tt_N4Tags(b,e,a){e=e||document;a=a||new Array();var c=(b=="a")?e.links:e.layers;for(var d=c.length;d--;){a[a.length]=c[d]}for(var d=e.layers.length;d--;){a=tt_N4Tags(b,e.layers[d].document,a)}return a}function tt_GetSelects(){if(!tt_op6&&!tt_ie){return}var b=tt_op6?"input":"select";if(document.all){var a=document.all.tags(b).length;while(a--){tt_inputs[a]=document.all.tags(b)[a]}}else{if(document.getElementsByTagName){var a=document.getElementsByTagName(b).length;while(a--){tt_inputs[a]=document.getElementsByTagName(b)[a]}}}var a=tt_inputs.length;while(a--){tt_inputs[a].x=0;tt_inputs[a].y=0;var c=tt_inputs[a];while(c){tt_inputs[a].x+=c.offsetLeft||0;tt_inputs[a].y+=c.offsetTop||0;c=c.offsetParent}}}function tt_Htm(a,j,k){var q=(typeof a.T_BGCOLOR!=tt_u)?a.T_BGCOLOR:ttBgColor,r=(typeof a.T_BGIMG!=tt_u)?a.T_BGIMG:ttBgImg,b=(typeof a.T_BORDERCOLOR!=tt_u)?a.T_BORDERCOLOR:ttBorderColor,o=(typeof a.T_BORDERWIDTH!=tt_u)?a.T_BORDERWIDTH:ttBorderWidth,h=(typeof a.T_FONTFACE!=tt_u)?a.T_FONTFACE:ttFontFace,i=(typeof a.T_FONTCOLOR!=tt_u)?a.T_FONTCOLOR:ttFontColor,p=(typeof a.T_FONTSIZE!=tt_u)?a.T_FONTSIZE:ttFontSize,n=(typeof a.T_FONTWEIGHT!=tt_u)?a.T_FONTWEIGHT:ttFontWeight,c=(typeof a.T_PADDING!=tt_u)?a.T_PADDING:ttPadding,m=(typeof a.T_SHADOWCOLOR!=tt_u)?a.T_SHADOWCOLOR:(ttShadowColor||0),g=(typeof a.T_SHADOWWIDTH!=tt_u)?a.T_SHADOWWIDTH:(ttShadowWidth||0),d=(typeof a.T_TITLE!=tt_u)?a.T_TITLE:"",l=(typeof a.T_TITLECOLOR!=tt_u)?a.T_TITLECOLOR:ttTitleColor,t=(typeof a.T_WIDTH!=tt_u)?a.T_WIDTH:ttWidth;if(m||g){m=m||"#cccccc";g=g||3}if(tt_n4&&(p=="10px"||p=="11px")){p="12px"}var s='<div class="tooltip1" id="'+j+'" style="position:absolute;z-index:300000;';s+="left:0px;top:0px;width:"+(t+g)+"px;visibility:"+(tt_n4?"hide":"hidden")+';">';s+='<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"'+(b?(' bgcolor="'+b+'"'):"")+' width="'+t+'">';if(d){s+='<tr><td style="padding-left:3px;"><font color="'+l+'" face="'+h+'" ';s+='style="color:'+l+";font-family:"+h+";font-size:"+p+';"><b>';s+=d+"</b></font></td></tr>"}s+='<tr><td><table border="0" cellpadding="'+c+'" cellspacing="'+o+'" width="100%">';s+="<tr><td"+(q?(' bgcolor="'+q+'"'):"")+(r?' background="'+r+'"':"");if(tt_n6){s+=' style="padding:'+c+'px;"'}s+='><font color="'+i+'" face="'+h+'"';s+=' style="color:'+i+";font-family:"+h+";font-size:"+p+";font-weight:"+n+';">';if(n=="bold"){s+="<b>"}s+=k;if(n=="bold"){s+="</b>"}s+="</font></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>";if(g){var f=Math.round(g*1.3);if(tt_n4){s+='<layer bgcolor="'+m+'" left="'+t+'" top="'+f+'" width="'+g+'" height="0"></layer>';s+='<layer bgcolor="'+m+'" left="'+f+'" align="bottom" width="'+(t-f)+'" height="'+g+'"></layer>'}else{var e=tt_n6?"-moz-opacity:0.85;":tt_ie?"filter:Alpha(opacity=85);":"";s+='<div id="'+j+'R" style="position:absolute;background:'+m+";left:"+t+"px;top:"+f+"px;width:"+g+"px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;"+e+'"></div>';s+='<div style="position:relative;background:'+m+";left:"+f+"px;top:0px;width:"+(t-f)+"px;height:"+g+"px;overflow:hidden;"+e+'"></div>'}}s+="</div>";return s}function tt_Init(){if(!(tt_op||tt_n4||tt_n6||tt_ie||tt_w3c)){return}var f=tt_n4?'<div style="position:absolute;"></div>':"",e,c,h,b="return escape(";var g=tt_tags.length;while(g--){e=tt_ie?(document.all.tags(tt_tags[g])||1):document.getElementsByTagName?(document.getElementsByTagName(tt_tags[g])||1):(!tt_n4&&tt_tags[g]=="a")?document.links:1;if(tt_n4&&(tt_tags[g]=="a"||tt_tags[g]=="layer")){e=tt_N4Tags(tt_tags[g])}var d=e.length;while(d--){if(typeof(c=e[d]).onmouseover=="function"&&c.onmouseover.toString().indexOf(b)!=-1&&!tt_n6||tt_n6&&(h=c.getAttribute("onmouseover"))&&h.indexOf(b)!=-1){if(h){c.onmouseover=new Function(h)}var a=unescape(c.onmouseover());f+=tt_Htm(c,"tOoLtIp"+g+""+d,a.wzReplace("& ","&"));c.onmouseover=new Function("e",'tt_Show(e,"tOoLtIp'+g+""+d+'",'+(typeof c.T_ABOVE!=tt_u)+","+((typeof c.T_DELAY!=tt_u)?c.T_DELAY:ttDelay)+","+((typeof c.T_FIX!=tt_u)?'"'+c.T_FIX+'"':'""')+","+(typeof c.T_LEFT!=tt_u)+","+((typeof c.T_OFFSETX!=tt_u)?c.T_OFFSETX:ttOffsetX)+","+((typeof c.T_OFFSETY!=tt_u)?c.T_OFFSETY:ttOffsetY)+","+(typeof c.T_STATIC!=tt_u)+","+(typeof c.T_STICKY!=tt_u)+");");c.onmouseout=tt_Hide;if(c.alt){c.alt=""}if(c.title){c.title=""}}}}document.write(f)}function tt_EvX(c){var a=tt_Int(c.pageX||c.clientX||0)+tt_Int(tt_ie?tt_db.scrollLeft:0)+tt_offX;if(a>xlim){a=xlim}var b=tt_Int(window.pageXOffset||(tt_db?tt_db.scrollLeft:0)||0);if(a<b){a=b}return a}function tt_EvY(b){var a=tt_Int(b.pageY||b.clientY||0)+tt_Int(tt_ie?tt_db.scrollTop:0);if(tt_above){a-=(tt_objH+tt_offY-(tt_op?31:15))}else{if(a>ylim||!tt_dwn&&a>ylim-24){a-=(tt_objH+5);tt_dwn=false}else{a+=tt_offY;tt_dwn=true}}return a}function tt_ReleasMov(){if(document.onmousemove==tt_Move){if(document.releaseEvents){document.releaseEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)}document.onmousemove=null}}function tt_HideInput(){if(!(tt_ie||tt_op6)||!tt_inputs){return}var b;var a=tt_inputs.length;while(a--){b=tt_inputs[a];if(tt_vis&&tt_objX+tt_objW>b.x&&tt_objX<b.x+b.offsetWidth&&tt_objY+tt_objH>b.y&&tt_objY<b.y+b.offsetHeight){b.style.visibility="hidden"}else{b.style.visibility="visible"}}}function tt_GetDiv(a){return(tt_n4?(document.layers[a]||null):tt_ie?(document.all[a]||null):(document.getElementById(a)||null))}function tt_GetDivW(){return(tt_n4?tt_obj.clip.width:tt_obj.style.pixelWidth?tt_obj.style.pixelWidth:tt_obj.offsetWidth)}function tt_GetDivH(){return(tt_n4?tt_obj.clip.height:tt_obj.style.pixelHeight?tt_obj.style.pixelHeight:tt_obj.offsetHeight)}function tt_SetDivZ(){var a=tt_obj.style||tt_obj;if(window.dd&&dd.z){a.zIndex=Math.max(dd.z+1,a.zIndex)}}function tt_SetDivPos(b,a){var d=tt_obj.style||tt_obj;var c=(tt_op6||tt_n4)?"":"px";d.left=(tt_objX=b)+c;d.top=(tt_objY=a)+c;tt_HideInput()}function tt_ShowDiv(a){if(tt_n4){tt_obj.visibility=a?"show":"hide"}else{tt_obj.style.visibility=a?"visible":"hidden"}tt_vis=a;tt_HideInput()}function tt_Show(i,d,l,e,f,g,k,j,n,c){if(tt_obj){tt_Hide()}var a=document.onmousemove||null;if(window.dd&&(window.DRAG&&a==DRAG||window.RESIZE&&a==RESIZE)){return}var b=document.onmouseup||null;if(a&&b){b(i)}tt_obj=tt_GetDiv(d);if(tt_obj){tt_dwn=!(tt_above=l);tt_static=n;tt_sticky=c;tt_objW=tt_GetDivW();tt_objH=tt_GetDivH();tt_offX=g?-(tt_objW+k):k;tt_offY=j;if(tt_op){tt_offY+=21}if(tt_n4){if(tt_obj.document.layers.length){var m=tt_obj.document.layers[0];m.clip.height=tt_objH-Math.round(m.clip.width*1.3)}}else{var m=tt_GetDiv(d+"R");if(m){var h=tt_objH-tt_Int(m.style.pixelTop||m.style.top||0);if(typeof m.style.pixelHeight!=tt_u){m.style.pixelHeight=h}else{m.style.height=h+"px"}}}tt_GetSelects();xlim=tt_Int((tt_db&&tt_db.clientWidth)?tt_db.clientWidth:window.innerWidth)+tt_Int(window.pageXOffset||(tt_db?tt_db.scrollLeft:0)||0)-tt_objW-(tt_n4?21:0);ylim=tt_Int(window.innerHeight||tt_db.clientHeight)+tt_Int(window.pageYOffset||(tt_db?tt_db.scrollTop:0)||0)-tt_objH-tt_offY;tt_SetDivZ();i=i||window.event;if(f){tt_SetDivPos(tt_Int((f=f.split(","))[0]),tt_Int(f[1]))}else{tt_SetDivPos(tt_EvX(i),tt_EvY(i))}window.tt_rdl=window.setTimeout("if (tt_sticky){tt_ReleasMov();window.tt_upFunc = document.onmouseup || null;if (document.captureEvents) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP);document.onmouseup = new Function(\"window.setTimeout('tt_Hide();', 10);\");}else if (tt_static) tt_ReleasMov();tt_ShowDiv('true');",e);if(!f){if(document.captureEvents){document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)}document.onmousemove=tt_Move}}}var tt_area=false;function tt_Move(a){if(!tt_obj){return}if(tt_n6||tt_w3c){if(tt_wait){return}tt_wait=true;setTimeout("tt_wait = false;",5)}var b=a||window.event;tt_SetDivPos(tt_EvX(b),tt_EvY(b));if(tt_op6){if(tt_area&&b.target.tagName!="AREA"){tt_Hide()}else{if(b.target.tagName=="AREA"){tt_area=true}}}}function tt_Hide(){if(window.tt_obj){if(window.tt_rdl){window.clearTimeout(tt_rdl)}if(!tt_sticky||tt_sticky&&!tt_vis){tt_ShowDiv(false);tt_SetDivPos(-tt_objW,-tt_objH);tt_obj=null;if(typeof window.tt_upFunc!=tt_u){document.onmouseup=window.tt_upFunc}}tt_sticky=false;if(tt_op6&&tt_area){tt_area=false}tt_ReleasMov();tt_HideInput()}}tt_Init();
```

Comment: What are you writing to position that element? Tooltip wrapper element should be positioned as absolute, and then onclick you have to get the position of the target element(over which you are adding tooltip). I guess you can check what you are getting for the top and left positions in IE9/10.

Comment: The position is absolute. I am using a Tootltip.js file.

Comment: Attaching Tooltip.js file in a minute.

Comment: Added the tooltip.js file's content.

Comment: Uhh... 14K of code, the name or a link would have been fine...

Comment: This library is a good example of how a working app can be ruined with browser detection... If you set `tt_ie = false;` before the first function in the library, you'll probably get this working in IE9+, but loose IE<9. Alternatively you can create more effective IE-check.